# How to generate a feed for this category within a Custom Post Type?

Tags: wordpress, rss

How do I generate a feed for the following category? http://digitalxfiles.com/item-cat/wordpress/

The posts in this category comes from a "post-type" so I want to display a category feed from the post type. I tried using ths: http://digitalxfiles.com/category/webhosting/feed/ But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a feed from a single custom post type by using this link format: `http://example.com/feed/?post_type=yourposttype`. You can add additional queries onto that if needed to go deeper, like specific categories. So, if you have the `item-cat` post type and you have the `wordpress` category, with an id of 42, your link would be: `http://example.com/feed/?post_type=item-cat&cat=42`.